# Some files not visible in xcode. But they are visible in finder

Tags: xcode

I am writing test cases for IOS. For that I created a new target for "IOS UI Testing" bundle and some files for writing test cases.
It created a folder "UITests" with some test files in it.

The problem is they are not visible in the xcode after xcode is restarted.
I am able to find the code in the finder and they are also recognized by the git. But not able to find them in the xcode

What might be the reason for this unpredictable behaviour?

Here's a screenshot of my xcode project, after I add the files manually.

[image]

Now, I can see the files, but I am unable to run my tests as it gives me error "Cannot load underlying module for XCTest".

Comment: what happens when you drop those files into your Xcode project's "UITests" folder?

Comment: It does gets added. But, I have to add it again and again after closing the xcode

Comment: My question is what causing this unpredictable behaviour?
Am I missing something?
And how do we solve it?

Comment: Right now, the only solution which I have is clone the project into new folder , create the testing files, then copy and paste the code in it.
This is not a feasible solution. so, looking for some concrete solution. Guys! Plz do help

Comment: could you edit your question to show a screenshot of the files in your project after you added them to your Xcode project? I'm wondering if it's a problem with the file extensions, or maybe the type of files (or file/folder group) in the project.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann, I have updated the question. Please do check.

Comment: A wild guess is that you discard changes in your `.pbxproj` file which actually saves your project hierarchy. But I may be very wrong.

Comment: Thanks @HunaidHassan . You got it right. I was discarding the changes in the .pbxproj file. Thank You very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. Thanks to @HunaidHassan.
whenever you do add a new target or a file. It gets referenced in the .pbxproj file. It saves the references of all the project files and its hierarchy.

I was discarding the changes done to pbxproj file, therby removing the references of newly created targets and files, which caused the files to disappear from the xcode